# Uncaught (in promise) URIError in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, encodeuricomponent

No response when clicking the “edit” buttons after updating the details with symbols. If without symbols, it responded when clicking the “edit” buttons.

[image: img1]

I have checked the console. The error messages are shown below:

```
history.js:93 Uncaught (in promise) URIError: Pathname "/branch-management/edit-branch/?companyName=ABC SDN BHD 1!@#$%^&*&branchName=ABC 1!@#$%^&*(" could not be decoded. This is likely caused by an invalid percent-encoding.
```

I have found that the problem, because it cannot cater symbol with the URL. Below is my coding:

```js
const selectRow = async (code, companyName, e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    history.push({
      pathname: `/branch-management/edit-branch/?companyName=${companyName}&branchName=${code}`,
    });
  };
```

I have tried below coding to solve it, but cannot solve:

```js
const selectRow = async (code, companyName, e) => {
    const encodedCompanyName = encodeURIComponent(companyName);
    const encodedCode = encodeURIComponent(code);
    e.preventDefault();
    history.push({
      pathname: `/branch-management/edit-branch/?companyName=${encodedCompanyName}&branchName=${encodedCode}`,
    });
  };
```

For `encodeURIComponent function`:

```js
declare function encodeURIComponent(uriComponent: string | number | boolean): string;
```

The error messages showed `Uncaught URIError: URI malformed`.

I hope someone can guide me on how to solve this problem.